# Error: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: amazon-redshift, union, mybatis, union-all

I'm getting this weird error due to union of two select statement that I'm using in annotation mybatis mapper. The same SQL is working fine in Redshift db.

```
select 
distinct
    'NW'||filtered_jobs.ptype||'-'||filtered_jobs.job_partition_value||'-SID-'||filtered_jobs.sid as dep_job_id
    ,CASE WHEN JOB_TYPE_ID=10 THEN 'PJ-' WHEN JOB_TYPE_ID=20 THEN 'CJ-' END||filtered_jobs.job_id as input_job_id
from filtered_jobs
union all
select 
distinct
    'NW'||final_subs.p_type||'-'||final_subs.p_value||'-DIF-'||final_subs.sid as dep_job_id
    ,CASE WHEN JOB_TYPE_ID=10 THEN 'PJ-' WHEN JOB_TYPE_ID=20 THEN 'CJ-' END||final_subs.job_id as input_job_id
from final_subs
```

I'm certain that this is because of using union, because it's working fine if either of the select statement is executed individually. That's why it's weird. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you provide the error message

Comment: The title is the error.

Comment: There is no co-related subquery in your code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes exactly my point.

Comment: are they external schemas?

Comment: @Hyruma92 no. actually filtered_jobs, final_subs are the temporary table created in the query which is working fine.